# top memory summary and process RES summation don't add up

Tags: linux, memory, top

I'm having hard time understanding memory usage reported by `top`. The memory summary section lists the following. All numbers in `MiB`.

```bash
MiB Mem :  31884.1 total,  13562.7 free,   7881.9 used,  10439.4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2048.0 free,      0.0 used.  22665.9 avail Mem
```

However, when I sum up `RES` column values, they don't add up to `used` reported in the summary. Summation of `RES` is `15225.7`. This is double `used` value of `7881.9`. If I add `used` and `buff/cache`, I get `18321.3`. So, now the summation of `used` and `buff/cache` is more than summation of `RES`.

More findings:

- Noticed that `top` memory summary almost matches that of `free`. The following is `free -m` output.

```bash
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31884        7881       13555         886       10446       22658
Swap:           2047           0        2047
```

As you can see, `used`, `free`, `buff/cache`, as well as, `available` all have almost the same values.

- When I add from `free` output the fields `used`, `shared`, and `buff/cache`, I get `19213`. This is again more than `RES` summation! This is expected, however, as we agreed that the output of `free` and `top` match from summary standpoint.
- I'm expecting that `RES` summation (from `top`) would be equal/close to summation of `used`, `shared`, and `buff/cache` (from `free`) as `top` documentation lists that memory per process factors in private and shared portions.

[image: quadrants pictorial explanation of memory types]

> ```
>       RES  - anything occupying physical memory which, beginning with
>             Linux-4.5, is the sum of the following three fields:
>             RSan - quadrant 1 pages, which include any
>                    former quadrant 3 pages if modified
>             RSfd - quadrant 3 and quadrant 4 pages
>             RSsh - quadrant 2 pages
> ```

- Whenever I clear system cache, `RES` summation always is more than the expected summation. This is how I clear system cache: `sudo sync && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=1`. Interestingly enough, `RES` summation upped to `18175.2`! The following is the memory summary of `top` after clearing the cache. You can notice significant decrease in `buff/cache`, as expected. However, I wasn't expecting significant increase in `used` field! Summation of `used`, `shared`, and `buff/cache` from `free` output is `13533`. This is around 5 GiB less than `RES` summation!

```bash
MiB Mem :  31884.1 total,  19358.2 free,   8795.6 used,   3730.2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2048.0 free,      0.0 used.  21626.5 avail Mem
```

- Tried `smem` and the values doesn't match either `top`, `free`, or summation of `RES`!

I can't make sense of the numbers! And I don't know, as a software application, how much memory an application I write actually takes and won't be able to investigate a memory issue if I run into one! I'm totally lost here. If someone can shed some light one what's going on, this will be much appreciated!

I looked at other questions but non actually addresses the inquiry. Like: [Why does the memory usage in "top" not add up?](https://superuser.com/q/282867/265896). [This one](https://superuser.com/q/259100/265896) was lucky their numbers checked out fine. .. and more, but still didn't find clear cut answer!

Looked at this one too: [Why total RES doesn't match used memory in top command? [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/358862/269618) Neither does this one ([Correctly determining memory usage in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34795/269618)) answer the question.